# Best Practice to store light arrays from tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, store

in my application I'm building a very basic mail template manager to save my users some time while writing several emails with the same subject/body.

I have a couple of tableviews where users can choose templates from the samples provided within the app or add/edit their own.

The mail template has 3 fields:

- template name (textfield)
- email subject (text field)
- email body (textview)
- template is default (BOOL)
- In the future I might implement the ability to attach a file (or a reference to it).

Now the samples within the app are hardcoded, but what would be the best way to store the user added templates on the phone?

To set a template as "default" I was thinking to add it to userDefaults, is it correct?
To save user templates on the phone, do I have to go with Core Data? Or is there an easiest way to go with?

If core data is the way to go does anybody have a link to a nice tutorial?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Personally Core Data in my opinion would be overkill for what you are after. You could add it to a `NSDictionary` and store that `NSDictionary` in `NSUserDefaults` like you were already considering. You could have something like

```
********WARNING THIS CODE IS UNTESTED********
// Probably best to rename this method something better but you get the idea
- (void)addTemplateWithSubject:(NSString *)subject Body:(NSString *)body forName:(NSString *)name shouldUseAsDefault:(BOOL)default
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    /* We want to retrieve ALL existing email template so we can check if 
     * our name already exists and if we have default already
     */
    NSMutableDictionary *existingEmailTemplates = [userDefaults dictionaryForKey:@"EmailTemplates"];

    // Now we have all our email templates lets see if one exists already
    if (![[existingEmailTemplates allKeys] containsObject:name]) {
        // If name doesn't exist lets start adding our new template
        NSMutableDictionary *emailTemplate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [emailTemplate addObject:subject forKey:@"subject"];
        [emailTemplate addObject:body forKey:@"body"];
        [emailTemplate addObject:name forKey:@"name"];
        // and anything else you which to add here

        // Add our new template to the rest of the templates
        [existingEmailTemplates addObject:emailTemplate forKey:name];

        // Now store our existing templates back into our NSUserDefaults
        [userDefaults setObject:existingEmailTemplates forKey:@"EmailTemplates"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    } else {
        // Oops our name already exists
        // Just fill this alert view to warn the user that it already exists
        UIAlertView *templateAlreadyExistsAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!".....]; 
        /*
         * You may at this point want to offer the user to delete the old template 
         * in favor of this new one. That isn't covered here if you do want it covered
         * just ask and I'll update.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Popeye. I'm trying to implement this and adapt it to my code, but I'm getting a couple or errors: xcode says "emailTemplate" cannot be MutableDictionary. Also I think to addObject for key doesn't seems to work, maybe is setValue forkey?

Comment: Please share the errors. As noted in the answer it is untested so I expected some.

Comment: Right I'm about to finish work and make my way home I will have a proper look at test when I get in. So maybe check back later or first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Did you had a chance to look again into this? Thanks!